# Не работает отправка post запроса Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь обработать нажатие кнопки в форме.

```
      <form id="AuthorizationForm" method="post">
      <p style="margin: 10px;">
       <input type="text" size="20" name="AuthorizationForm_email" class="inputLogin" placeholder="Ваш email">
       <input type="password" size="20" name="AuthorizationForm_password" class="inputLogin" placeholder="Ваш пароль">
       </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="submitLogin">
  </form>
```

Вот код js

```js
$("#AuthorizationForm").submit(function(event) {
  alert("Поймали submit");
  return false;
});
```

```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <form id="AuthorizationForm" method="post">
          <p style="margin: 10px;">
           <input type="text" size="20" name="AuthorizationForm_email" class="inputLogin" placeholder="Ваш email">
           <input type="password" size="20" name="AuthorizationForm_password" class="inputLogin" placeholder="Ваш пароль">
           </p>
          <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="submitLogin">
      </form>
```

При нажатии на submit меня редиректит на index.php и алерт не появляется.

id формы уникальный, jquery подключен. 
Единственное на что я думаю, данная форма создается модально, изначально она имеет статус display:none.

p/s заметил что после добавления формы авторизации, хром пишет в инспектор:
**(index):1 This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see**

Временно решил так:

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="AuthorizationForm_input" value="Отправить" name="pipo" class="submitLogin">
```

jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#AuthorizationForm_input', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('click')
    });
});
```

Comment: `alert` появляется?

Answer (score 3):

У вас нет отмены действия по умолчанию(`event.preventDefault();`).

```
$(document).on('submit', "#AuthorizationForm", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: А чем это лучше?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click здесь описано чем лучше

Comment: ни чем, это делается для того если форма подгружается ajax-ом

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал ваш вариант. ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Waik хм не знаю у меня работает, нормально. какой браузер испоьзуете?

Comment: preventDefa**u**lt

Answer (score 2):

Скрипт

```
$("#AuthorizationForm").submit(function(event) {
  alert("Поймали submit");
  return false;
});
```

находится на странице выше элемента формы. Когда он вызывается, элемента еще нет в дереве, выборка `$("#AuthorizationForm")` - пустая.

```
$(function() {
  $("#AuthorizationForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("Поймали submit");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проверил ваш код. Дополнительно установил его перед закрывающим <body>, не помогло, все ровно редирект на главную происходит.

Comment: @Waik `alert` появляется?

Comment: Не появляется. 
p/s заметил что после добавления формы авторизации, хром пишет в инспектор:
**(index):1 This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see**